# Android - can service be run in untill app gets uninstalled?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contacts, contentobserver

I need to get notified when phone contacts changed, even if my app is closed. how to do?

In my code I am starting service with START_STICKY in splash screen, but when I close the app, service also starting again.

When I change in contacts, ContentObserver class's onchange called multiple times. 
And some time onchange is not being called.
So how to achieve solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can call your service at start up when boot completed message broadcast by android.

as explained in here [Start service on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)